# cohen kappa per item put in one dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple items and subitems in which I want to calculate the kappa per item, with the `irr` package using `kappa2()`. for every item there is a '_1' and '_2', so; item1_1 and item1_2. which represents the first and second moment of data measuring.

An example of the dataframe:

***edit:***

```
items <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 51, ncol = 41))
# Set the column names for the first column and items columns
colnames(items) <- c("ID", paste(rep(paste0("item", 1:20), each = 2), c("_1", "_2"), sep = ""))
# Fill the ID column with values 1 to 51
items$ID <- 1:51
# Fill the item columns with random 0's and 1's
set.seed(123) # Set seed for reproducibility
items[, 2:41] <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), size = 20 * 2 * 51, replace = TRUE), ncol = 40)
# Show the resulting data frame
items
```

I want a dataframe which would look something like this:

```
item    method      subjects    raters     irr.name   value    stat.name    statistic   p.value
1     Cohenskappa..    51         2          Kappa    0.536..      Z           3.897     0.023947
2     Cohenskappa..    51         2          Kappa    0.705..      Z           5.757     0.000002
3     Cohenskappa..    51         2          Kappa    0.890..      Z           6.447     0.072732
4     Cohenskappa..    51         2          Kappa    0.236..      Z           3.429     0.005636
..
20    Cohenskappa..    51         2          Kappa    0.686..      Z           4.897     0.000056
```

An option is creating single dataframes for every item and calculating the kappa, but this eventually result in wil result in more than 76 dataframes. There should be a more compact and quicker way.

Comment: you could work with the "dplyr" library and use the "mutate" function to add new columns with your kappa-value.

Comment: @demi thanks I misunderstood the example data you had posted but I see now. Do you want the weighted or unweighted kappa?

Comment: If you edit the question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data, the differences between that and what I generated should be clear, and we can work out what needs to change.

Comment: @demi thanks for editing the post with some data. I just tried the code in my answer with the data you posted and it doesn't generate an error - I get a data frame of results (with a couple of warnings about confidence intervals being truncated to 1/-1 but that's OK). Do you get the error with this sample data? If so, what does `packageVersion("psych")` produce? I am using version `2.2.9`.

Comment: @demi also I've just noticed that your code `kappa_list <- lapply(col_names_list, (item) get_kappa(item, items))` should be `kappa_list <- lapply(col_names_list, \(item) get_kappa(item, items))` (you're missing a backslash). But that would give you a syntax error rather than the error you posted so I assume that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using the `psych` package, which will handle `NA` values for you. I've created a helper function `get_kappa()` which formats the [`psych::cohen.kappa()`](https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/kappa.html) output for each item into a data frame. We can then iterate over each item using `lapply()` and bind all the data frames together.

All the data wrangling is using base R. Generally I prefer to put the data in long form, which can be easier to manipulate with `tidyverse` or `data.table` functions. However, `psych` often takes the data in wide form so I've left it in this case. Base R functions like `split()` and `lapply()` are good at iterating over data frames in wide form.

```r
library(psych)
get_kappa <- function(item, dat) {
    k <- cohen.kappa(dat[item])
    df <- data.frame(
        kappa_unweighted = k$confid["unweighted kappa", "estimate"],
        kappa_weighted = k$confid["weighted kappa", "estimate"],
        p = k$plevel
    )

    df
}

# item_1_1, item_1_2 etc.
col_names <- grep("^item", names(dat), v = T)
# list with two elements per item, e.g. c("item_1_1", "item_1_2")
col_names_list <- split(col_names, gsub("_[1|2]$", "", col_names))

kappa_list <- lapply(col_names_list, \(item)
    get_kappa(item, dat)
)
kappa_df <- do.call(rbind, kappa_list)
head(kappa_df)
#         kappa_unweighted kappa_weighted    p
# item_1         0.8646018      0.8377665 0.05
# item_10        0.7101006      0.4448613 0.05
# item_11        0.8678756      0.8470442 0.05
# item_12        0.7543783      0.6648501 0.05
# item_13        0.8647813      0.8316684 0.05
# item_14        0.8208169      0.8091446 0.05
```

#### Data

In general it's best to include some sample data in your question. In this case it was relatively straightforward so I generated some using this code:

```r
set.seed(11111)
N <- 51
col_names <- paste0(rep(paste0("item_", 1:20), each = 2), c("_1", "_2"))
ground_truth <- lapply(1:20, \(.) sample(0:9, N, replace = TRUE)) |>
    setNames(paste0("item_", 1:20))

ratings <- lapply(col_names, \(x) {
    item_num <- gsub("_[1|2]$", "", x)
    item_truth <- ground_truth[[item_num]]
    to_change <- as.logical(sample(0:1, N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1)))
    item_truth[to_change] <- 0
    item_truth
})
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:N)
dat[col_names] <- ratings
```